# Get-Help about* doesn't work on non-English system

Tags: powershell, localization, powershell-3.0, culture

I'm using the German PS version and I'm trying
to display the [about topics of powershell v. 3.0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847856.aspx) using the command

```
Get-Help about_*
```

This seems to be the right command to list the topics. Also I updated the PS help using

```
Update-Help
```

CMDlet, just in case the about topics would be missing. Anyway: the Get-Help cmdlet processes and returns: nothing. Using `fl` to format the output or saving the output to a variable didn't help, the about topics are not found at all. However, in general the wildcard seems to work. Running

```
get-help get-*
```

works like a charm. 
Any Ideas?

Comment: are the about*.txt files available in %windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\en-US

Comment: Nope. I don't even have a en-US folder since I'm using the german PS version. But within the de-DE folder no about*.txt files are to be found either.

Comment: PS v4+ [update](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/767899/please-add-uiculture-to-get-help): "We enabled this scenario in PowerShell 4.0 by adding logic to fall back to en-US if help content isn't available in the current culture."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

update-help is not "localised", so use this : `Update-Help -UICulture "en-us"`
you should now see the .txt files

you can check here for a modified get-help function that allow you to specify the culture to use : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/6cb7fb10-f80e-41fc-bee7-6adda66f311a

Comment: That worked. Thanks! It's funny: I already tried that before and it was not working since I was missing the "en-Us" help (I was assuming en-US is there by default).

Comment: ++; just to clarify: `Update-Help` _itself_ IS localized: it looks for help content in the current culture's language; what _isn't_ localized for many cultures yet is the help _content_. On PS v4+, using `Get-Help` falls back to English (`en-US`) help, if no content is available for the current culture.