# Why I get other result for the `get-Help about_*` expression?

Tags: powershell

PowerShell 4.0

I read the [Getting Started with PowerShell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1783558504) book. I try author's code but I get the other result... The screen of the book page (with my comment):

[image]

Read my comment on the screen, please. I get such results:

[image]

[image]

Why I get other results?

Comment: Have you tried `Update-Help` to download the help files first?

Comment: @ Frode F, yes I have. But how it can affect at the result that expression?

Comment: @AndreyBushman: To complement [Matt Gartman's helpful answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34925128/45375): If `Update-Help` failed and you happen to have only _one_ topic installed that matches `about_*`, `get-help` will display that topic's content instead of printing all matching topics in list form.

Comment: Hey...that's my book!  :-)

Comment: It is very useful book. Thank you for your work @Mike. Your material is very clear for me. I recomend this book for our IT for reading also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen this same issue on several machines.  `Update-Help` appears to execute successfully when run from a normal PowerShell window, but does not actually update many of the help files.

The solution is to run Update-Help from an elevated PowerShell window (Run as Administrator).  Once this completes you should have all of the expected help files.

You may also have to specify the `-UICulture` parameter since Update-Help may not be utilizing your localization settings as seen in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003380/get-help-about-doesnt-work).

You can use this command to update help for your language:

```
 Update-Help -UICulture (Get-Culture).Name
```

Comment: Thank you for the useful info about the `-UICulture` flag.

Comment: @AndreyBushman Strange I haven't seen issues with having to restart the PowerShell session before.  You can see the help txt files in %windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\{culture} so in the future you can see if Update-Help is actually putting the files in that location.  Glad its working for you now!

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason of my problem...

I had launched `Updated-Help` with admin rights, of course, but **I didn't restart the `PowerShell` session** and got that unexpected result. Later I restarted PowerShell and saw that all works fine after restarting.

I didn't think that application restarting can be necessary at this case.

Comment: Restarting _shouldn't_ be necessary (from v3 `get-help Update-Help`: "You can use the Get-Help cmdlet to view the new help files immediately; _you do not need to restart Windows PowerShell to make the change effective._"), so it would be helpful to know what's going on. Perhaps running `Update-Help -Debug -Verbose` will tell you more.

Comment: Possibly something another affected to the result. I noticed that the problem desappeared after I restarted the `PowerShell_ISE.exe`.