# Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables not working

Tags: powershell

I'm studying PowerShell and both on sites and books it is suggested to call `Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables` to, for example, get the list of automatic variables returned. I tried calling `Get-Help` with the following arguments but I always get a list of cmdlets returned:

- about_Variables
- about_Automatic_Variables
- about_Environment_Variables
- about_Preference_Variables
- about_Scopes

What is it that I'm mistaking?

Comment: I can reproduce this in v5. It is not about_Automatic_Variables specifically since I get the same results from `get-help about_Automatic_Vari. I don't know if this is a bug or not though. Needs more investigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So [the solution from powershell.org](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/powershell-missing-about_-help-topics-after-running-update-help/)  is:

```
Install-Script -Name Install-AboutHelp
```

in a Administrator powershell to get the missing helpfile.

Comment: I would include the link to where you got this information in the answer as well. Since comments dont exist forever.

Comment: I use PS 7.1 Core and it does not work, the link does not work either: `Get-Help: Get-Help could not find about_automatic_variables in a help file..`. `Install-Script install-abouthelp` most like worked.

Answer (score 5):

You probably have to *update your help* using:

```
Update-Help
```

Then you should be able to retrieve it using:

```
get-help about_Automatic_Variables
```

Comment: Yes. His help is not complete. `Get-Help "about_*"` should prove that. The results he gets is still odd though.

Comment: I confirm that executing `Get-Help "about_*"` does not list  `about_Automatic_Variables`. I repeated the `update-help` as an admin continuing on errors and yet, still now, `about_Automatic_Variables` is not listed. What is it that I'm missing or not doing right?

Comment: In the end I found the solution to my problem at https://powershell.org/forums/topic/powershell-missing-about_-help-topics-after-running-update-help/. Executed `Install-Script -Name Install-AboutHelp` and
`Install-AboutHelp.ps1` and you'll get the missing about_* helpfile.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. You might add this as an answer and accept it to help other.

Answer (score 1):

Read this:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx

I got this from my browser.  It was the first hit when I searched for "about automatic variables".  It won't hurt to update the help inside your copy of PS, as has been suggested in another answer.  And for a list of current variables,  just do this:

```
PS> gci variable:
```

Answer (score 0):

Do You maybe have language other than English set and Powershell V5? 
if Yes - than  here's Your answer 
[Missing Help Files in Powershell V5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39338409/missing-help-files-in-powershell-v5-0)

Comment: My culture is en-us and even after update-help (that btw breaks and stops on updating SqlServer module) the behavior remains the same, probably the same that @Matt is seeing, a list of cmdlet returned starting with ForEach-Object.